# Is this object KVC-compliant?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, kvc

I'm trying to understand how to use Bindings in Xcode. I have this class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface OddsItem : NSObject {
    NSMutableDictionary *properties;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *properties;

@end
```

and

```
#import "OddsItem.h"


@implementation OddsItem {

}
@synthesize properties;

- (void)dealloc {
    [properties release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Is this KVC-compliant? The examples I've found seem to be from before the days of synthesized properties.

If it isn't KVC-compliant what must I do to make it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generated methods from `@synthesized` are KVO-comliant.

As long as you change the property using the setter method it will be KVO-compliant.

If however you change the instance variable directly it won't be. In that case you will have to manually call `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:`.

Comment: What about when I override the getter/setter methods of my `synthesised`? In getter and setter I am allowed to directly access `_properties` right?